# Generic Getter for a collection of Service classes?

Tags: c#, class, generics, model-view-controller, factory

I'm building an application in Unity-C#, where everything is referenced under an `App` class in an MVC pattern. An `App` instance will make use of several Service classes for doing different data-related things, and all of these Service classes derive from `Service.ServiceAbstract`, which only contains a basic constructor as well as a Getter for a reference to the relevant `App` instance.

Ideally what I want is for the `App` instance to itself create and store all of the services in some kind of container, as well as have a Getter method to return a reference to a requested service. Currently, it is done like this;

```
private Dictionary<Service.ServiceNames, Service.ServiceAbstract> _services = null;

public Service.ServiceAbstract GetService(Service.ServiceNames serviceName)
{
    return _services[serviceName] as Service.ServiceAbstract;
}
```

The problems I'm having with this implementation are twofold;

1. `Service.ServiceNames` is an enum, which increases the maintainability requirement every time a new Service class has to be created.
2. The way to retrieve a method inside one of these services looks like this;

   `((Service.AudioService)[Service.ServiceNames.AUDIO]).DoSomething();`

   This becomes unwieldy when I need to pass data from one service to another;

   `((Service.ErrorService)[Service.ServiceNames.ERROR]).CreateErrorPopup(((Service.LocaleService)[Service.ServiceNames.LOCALE]).GetString("GENERIC_ERROR"));`

What I would like is some kind of generic method that can take in the Type of Service to get, and then return a reference to that service, without any need to cast or use enums by the callers. I know of the existence of `<T>` Generics, but I've never created something with them and I'm unsure of a good way to store my services and then return them directly.

Comment: As of right now there are 10 services for different things the app needs to do (network communications, file loading, authentication etc.). As well as Services, there are also Screens and Components that represent the View of MVC, and they also need access to Services. Feeding all of the necessary service references to every class on their constructor would become unwieldy to maintain in my opinion. I'd much rather just have one core object be responsible for containing and giving references to the necessary services when needed.

Comment: PS For your `LocaleService` you can use indexers instead of `GetString` method, as they *may* make sense in this case and will also shorten the code. Reference: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/puranindia/indexers-in-C-Sharp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Type` instead of `enum`. In this case you can utilize generic function and type casting.

```
private Dictionary<Type, Service.ServiceAbstract> _services = null;

public T GetService<T>()
{
    return _services[typeof(T)] as T;
}

// And then use

GetService<Service.ErrorService>().CreateErrorPopup(GetService<Service.LocaleService>().GetString("GENERIC_ERROR"));
```

If you want to initialize your services with default constructor and **if** you will not have concurrent threads calling `GetService<T>()` you can use this code as well, that will assist you to not initialize `_services` manually.

```
public T GetService<T>() where T : new()
{
    if(!_services.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
    {
        _services[typeof(T)] = new T();
    }
    return _services[typeof(T)] as T;
}
```